# Is it possible to get different results from solving a model using CPLEX in MATLAB and CPLEX in Java?

Tags: java, matlab, cplex

I am solving a linear binary optimization model using CPLEX. I have coded the model in both MATLAB and JAVA. The optimum value of objective function resulting from both JAVA and MATLAB programming are same. However optimal variable values are different. It is possible to have several optimum solutions for my model. I was wondering if it is possible to have different optimal values for variables resulting from applying CPLEX in MATLAB and JAVA?

Comment: Reading at @TheBat answer, there is a doc on deterministic algorithms in the help section of CPLEX. "To force CPLEX to use deterministic algorithms in all cases, set the parallel mode parameter to 1". http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2FContent%2FOptimization%2FDocumentation%2FCPLEX%2F_pubskel%2FCPLEX864.html . I don't know CPLEX thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Under the hood, these languages act completely different and not just a byte code vs compiled code difference. You can write code in C code and run it through different compilers and have the results of running the code be different. If any floating point math is done, different optimizations are done by the compiler to speed up the code. Ideally a single compiler will always perform the floating point math in the same order after optimizations (so even if the code is slightly different with the same expected output, it will be the same), this assumption cannot not be held across multiple compilers/languages/hardware since floating point numbers are incredibly picky.

I haven't read this whole document, but it might be of interest to you:
http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/floating-point-determinism/

Comment: Thank you so much. That was so helpful to know!